# 'environment.ts' is not under 'rootDir' Angular Library build error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module, angular-library

I am trying to read the environment variable from the Angular 9 library, but getting an error while building the library

Here is the implementation

import { EnvironmentViewModel } from 'projects/falcon-core/src/lib/view-models/environment-view-model';

```
class EnvironmentImpl implements EnvironmentViewModel {
  production = false;
  openID = {
    authority: "https://dev-816623.okta.com/oauth2/XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    client_id: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:4200",
    response_type: "code",
    scope : "openid profile email"
  }
}

export const environment = new EnvironmentImpl();
```

**View Model**

```
export abstract class EnvironmentViewModel {
    abstract readonly production: boolean;
    abstract readonly openID: IOpenIdViewModel;
}

export declare interface IOpenIdViewModel {
    authority?: string;
    client_id?: string;
    redirect_uri?: string;
    response_type?: string;
    scope?: string;
    silent_redirect_uri?: string;
    post_logout_redirect_uri?: string;
    filterProtocolClaims?: boolean
    loadUserInfo?: boolean
    automaticSilentRenew?: boolean;
    monitorSession?: boolean;
    accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime?: number;
    checkSessionInterval?: number;
    silentRequestTimeout?: number;
}
```

**In the Module**

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
 providers: [
    { provide: EnvironmentViewModel, useValue: environment }
  ]
```

**tsconfig.lib.json**

```
   {
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "target": "es2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": [],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "enableResourceInlining": true
  },
  "includes": ["../../src/environments/environment.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@falcon/core": [
        "dist/@falcon-ng/core"
      ]
    }
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

keep getting the error as

```
ERROR: projects/falcon-core/src/lib/falcon-core.module.ts:28:29 - error TS6059: File '/Users/macbook/Projects/project-falcon/src/environments/environment.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/Users/macbook/Projects/project-falcon/projects/falcon-core/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

28 import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

Reference https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/208

Comment: Please share your tsconfig.json files, the problem is there.

Comment: @satanTime do you mean the library one tsconfig.lib.json ?

Comment: yes, usually you should have several - one in root, and 1 or 2 in src for the app and for specs.

Comment: Updated the tsconfig.lib.json file

Comment: you need also to share `"extends": "../../tsconfig.json",` it's a parent one.

Comment: @satanTime Done mate

Comment: Great, if nobody helps I'll be back in 2-3 hours and post info. Meanwhile you can try to add to the first one `lib` `includes: ["../../src/environments/environment.ts"]`

Comment: Naah, it is not working :(

Comment: good, then in 2 hours I'll be back.

Comment: Hi, checking it again

Comment: it should be `include`, not `includes`, could you check if it works?

Comment: Naaah, it didn't work.

Comment: ah, sad sad sad

Answer (score 2):

Found a better solution

**Library module**

```
export class FalconCoreModule {
    public static forRoot(environment: any): ModuleWithProviders {
      return {
        ngModule: FalconCoreModule,
        providers: [{ provide: EnvironmentViewModel, useValue: environment }]
      };
    }
}
```

Now the project who is consuming this library pass the environment variable as root element.

```
import {environment} from "../environments/environment";
@NgModule({
            declarations: [],
            imports:[
                FalconCoreModule.forRoot(environment)
            ],
            bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
```

Comment: Did you get the solution this, the above didn't worked for me.